# What does kubelet do if you delete the node?

Tags: kubernetes

In a Kubernetes cluster, if you delete a node from the API server, how does the corresponding machine's kubelet respond?

Does it send a request to the API server to recreate the node resource, or does it shutdown and restart the machine?